# Scroll Bar not showing after applying theme only on IE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i've applied a theme to my web application by SharePoint 2010 
after doing this and when i went to add an item to any list i didn't get the scroll bar on IE but i'm Getting on Chrome 
The image will explain more 
1- Chrome
[image]

2- IE
[image: with IE]

Answer (score 2):

This looks as if you have the complete master page applied to the list form.

For e.g. the site banner and the search box are showing on the list form.

You should add the class `s4-notdlg` to all master page elements that are not required in a list form.

If the problem persists after that, post more details.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn but i need some more details as i'm an System Engineer and it's my 1st time to deal with those sttafs